# How can i save JTextField components in a .txt file? (Using Netbeans GUI)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, file-io, jtextfield

This is what I have made by now,
I'm trying to do a java project but I really want to see some examples to understand the way i can make it happen.If I want to take all jtextfield components and save it into a file

```
    public class Lift extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public Lift()
        {
            super("Lift Maintenance");
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jLabel1.setText("Lift maintenance:");

            jLabel2.setText("Lift parts:");

            jLabel3.setText("Technician:");

            jButton1.setText("NEXT");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton2.setText("BACK");
            jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton3.setText("CLEAR");
            jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton4.setText("EXIT");
            jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                        .add(jLabel1)
                        .add(jLabel3)
                        .add(jLabel2))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                        .add(jTextField2)
                        .add(jTextField3)
                        .add(jTextField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 83, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(jButton3)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(jButton4)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(jButton2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                    .add(jButton1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel1)
                        .add(jTextField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(20, 20, 20)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel2)
                        .add(jTextField2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(18, 18, 18)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel3)
                        .add(jTextField3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 146, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jButton3)
                        .add(jButton4)
                        .add(jButton2)
                        .add(jButton1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
            jTextField3.setText("");
        }                                        

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            this.dispose();
            coOwnerShip C=new coOwnerShip();
            C.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           this.dispose();
           HeatingCost h=new HeatingCost();
           h.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            System.exit(0);
        }                                        


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Lift().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

Another class again....

```
    public class coOwnerShip extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /** Creates new form coOwnerShip */
        public coOwnerShip()
        {
            super("Co=Ownership Cost");
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jLabel1.setText("Taxis:");

            jLabel2.setText("Co-Ownership cost:");

            jButton1.setText("NEXT");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton2.setText("BACK");
            jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton3.setText("CLEAR");
            jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton4.setText("EXIT");
            jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                        .add(jLabel2)
                        .add(jLabel1)
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(jButton3)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(jButton4)))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(jButton2)
                    .add(9, 9, 9)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                            .add(jTextField2)
                            .add(jTextField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .add(jButton1))
                    .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(40, 40, 40)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel1)
                        .add(jTextField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel2)
                        .add(jTextField2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 199, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jButton3)
                        .add(jButton4)
                        .add(jButton2)
                        .add(jButton1)))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            this.dispose();
            BuildingCostOutputStream b=new BuildingCostOutputStream();
            b.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            this.dispose();
            Lift l=new Lift();
            l.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            System.exit(0);
        }                                        


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new coOwnerShip().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

Here goes the second JFrame class...

```
    public class BuildingCostOutputStream extends javax.swing.JFrame {


        public BuildingCostOutputStream()
        {
            super("Building Output Stream");
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jLabel1.setText("Username:");

            jLabel2.setText("PassWord:");

            jLabel3.setText("Building Code:");

            jLabel4.setText("Month:");

            jLabel5.setText("Year:");

            jLabel6.setText("Maintenance Cost:");

            jLabel7.setText("Heating Cost:");

            jLabel8.setText("Co-Ownership Cost:");

            jTextField7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jTextField7ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton1.setText("NEXT");

            jButton2.setText("SAVE");

            jButton3.setText("BACK");
            jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton4.setText("CLEAR");
            jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton5.setText("EXIT");
            jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(163, 163, 163)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                .add(jLabel1)
                                .add(jLabel2))
                            .add(34, 34, 34)
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                                .add(jTextField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 389, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, jPasswordField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 389, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                .add(jLabel3)
                                .add(jLabel4)
                                .add(jLabel6)
                                .add(jLabel7)
                                .add(jLabel8))
                            .add(21, 21, 21)
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, jTextField2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 204, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, jTextField5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 98, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, jTextField3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 98, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, jTextField6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 98, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, jTextField7, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 98, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                    .add(106, 106, 106)))
                            .add(1, 1, 1)
                            .add(jLabel5)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(jTextField4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addContainerGap())
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(jButton4)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                            .add(jButton5)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(jButton2)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(jButton3)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(jButton1))))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel1)
                        .add(jTextField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jPasswordField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(jLabel2))
                    .add(14, 14, 14)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                        .add(jLabel3)
                        .add(jTextField2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(18, 18, 18)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                            .add(jTextField4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .add(jLabel5)
                            .add(jLabel4))
                        .add(jTextField3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(18, 18, 18)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel6)
                        .add(jTextField5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel7)
                        .add(jTextField6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(30, 30, 30)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jLabel8)
                        .add(jTextField7, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 107, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(jButton1)
                        .add(jButton5)
                        .add(jButton4)
                        .add(jButton3)
                        .add(jButton2)))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
            jTextField3.setText("");
            jTextField4.setText("");
            jTextField5.setText("");
            jTextField6.setText("");
            jTextField7.setText("");
        }                                        

        private void jTextField7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                           

        private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            this.dispose();
            coOwnerShip C=new coOwnerShip();
            C.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           System.exit(0);
        }                                        


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new BuildingCostOutputStream().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
        private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

Comment: By JTextField components, do you mean the text entered into the text field?

Comment: Exactly...I want to write text in the JTextField and save it in a txt file.The text should be from the first and the second class i have created so it can be in the same .txt file!

Comment: Ok, I'm writing an answer right now.

Comment: Thank you very much it really helped...I will go and try it right now(if I have any problem I will post a comment!)

Comment: Dude I have a problem about where I should write this code part...Do I need to go to every single JTextFiled(then go it's actionPerformed()) or is there an option about writing all these lines of code together ?

Comment: What you can do is make a void with all of the lines of code and then make each actionPerformed reference that void.

Comment: Can you write me an example please ?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing we need to do is get the text from a `JTextField` and store it in a `String`, like this:

```
String textFieldVal = yourTextField.getText();
```

Then, we have to write the value to a text file, like this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("textFieldOutput.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println(textFieldVal);
writer.close();
```

So, this is what it would look like in your first class:

```
String textField1Val = jTextField1.getText();
String textField2Val = jTextField2.getText();
String textField3Val = jTextField3.getText();
String textField4Val = jTextField4.getText();
String textField5Val = jTextField5.getText();
String textField6Val = jTextField6.getText();
String textField7Val = jTextField7.getText();
```

And when you want to save it to a text file:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("textFieldOutput.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("First text field:");
writer.println(textField1Val);
writer.println("Second text field:");
writer.println(textField2Val);
writer.println("Third text field:");
writer.println(textField3Val);
writer.println("Fourth text field:");
writer.println(textField4Val);
writer.println("Fifth text field:");
writer.println(textField5Val);
writer.println("Sixth text field:");
writer.println(textField6Val);
writer.println("Seventh text field:");
writer.println(textField7Val);
writer.close();
```

However, this will overwrite the file if it already exists, so in your other classes, do this:

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("textFieldOutput.txt", true)))) {
writer.println(textField1Val);
writer.println(textField2Val);
// etc...
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

That way, it will add to the file instead of erasing all the text. I hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Here is an example `ActionListener` referencing a single void with all of the code:

```
jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                saveText(evt);
            }
        });
```

And somewhere else in your class:

```
private void saveText(evt) {
    String textField1Val = jTextField1.getText();
    String textField2Val = jTextField2.getText();
    String textField3Val = jTextField3.getText();
    String textField4Val = jTextField4.getText();
    String textField5Val = jTextField5.getText();
    String textField6Val = jTextField6.getText();
    String textField7Val = jTextField7.getText();

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("textFieldOutput.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println("First text field:");
    writer.println(textField1Val);
    writer.println("Second text field:");
    writer.println(textField2Val);
    writer.println("Third text field:");
    writer.println(textField3Val);
    writer.println("Fourth text field:");
    writer.println(textField4Val);
    writer.println("Fifth text field:");
    writer.println(textField5Val);
    writer.println("Sixth text field:");
    writer.println(textField6Val);
    writer.println("Seventh text field:");
    writer.println(textField7Val);
    writer.close();
}
```